# Send object in response headers Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, mean

I need to send an object in my response headers, but when I access it I only see `[object object]` no error and nothing else.
What could possibly be the problem ?
here's how I'm sending from my server

```
pagination = {
    'pageSize': 25,
    'someInformation': 'blablabla...'
}
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Pagination');
res.setHeader('X-Pagination', pagination);
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want the value of the `X-Pagination` header to show?  Remember, headers are just text in http.  What text do you want in that one line header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So header values are strings. When you pass an `object` to a function that needs string it uses the `Object.toString()` property and uses it.

```
const obj = {a:1}
obj.toString() // outputs "[object Object]"
```

In order to pass JSON you need to use `JSON.stringify` In your case it will be:

```
pagination = {
    'pageSize': 25,
    'someInformation': 'blablabla...'
}
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Pagination');
res.setHeader('X-Pagination', JSON.stringify(pagination));
```

**This is current output:**

[image]